# Update a Mongoose Document

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer, cloudinary

I am trying to update a User record in mongoDB with both text and images simultaneously. I am using both multer and cloudinary to upload the images and then save the public_url in the Database.
The text documents saves and its succesfully persists on the DB, but for reasons I don't know, the image_url for the images are not persisting.

Here is my UserModel.js file

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique: true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        select:false
    },
    role:{
        type:String,
        enum:['buyer','ESP',"admin"],
        default:'buyer'
    },
    referer:{
        type:String,
    },
    firstname:{
        type:String,
    },
    lastname:{
        type:String,   
    },
    country:{
        type:String,
    },
    state:{
        type:String,      
    },
    lga:{
        type:String,      
    },
    gender:{
        type:String,  
    },
    phone1:{
        type:Number,
    },
    phone2:{
        type:Number,
    },
    date_of_birth: {
        type: Date
    },
    occupation: {
        type: String
    },
    address:{
        type:String,
    },
    pictureupload:{
    type: String,
   },
   idupload:{
    type: String,
   },
   kin:{
        type: KinSchema,
        
    },
},{
    timestamps:true
})
```

Here is my UserRoute File

```
router.patch('/profile',verifyToken, uploadPhotos.array('images'), async (req, res ) => {
  const urls = [];
  const user = req.user;
  const body = req.body;
  const files = req.files;

  validateUserDetails(body, (e, values)=> {
    if(e) {
      return res.json({ error: { message: e.details[0].message } });
    }
  })

  if(!files) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "No files attached!" })
  }

  try {
    files.forEach(file => {
      cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.path, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
          console.log(err.message);
          return res.send(err.message)
        }
        urls.push(result.public_id);
      })
    });

    body.pictureupload = urls[0];
    body.idupload = urls[1];

    // Extracting
    const {
      firstname,
      lastname,
      gender,
      country,
      state,
      city,
      lga,
      phone1,
      phone2,
      date_of_birth,
      occupation,
      address,
      pictureupload,
      idupload,
      referer
    } = body

    const updatedProfile = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, 
      {
        firstname,
        lastname,
        gender,
        country,
        state,
        city,
        lga,
        phone1,
        phone2,
        date_of_birth,
        occupation,
        address,
        pictureupload,
        idupload,
        referer
      },
      {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
      }
    )
    
    if(!updatedProfile) {
      console.log(error.message);
    return res.status(400).json({status:'failed', message: 'failed to update Profile'});
    }
    console.log(updatedProfile);
    return res.status(200).json({ status:'success', message: updatedProfile})

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
  }

})
```

The images saves successfully on Cloudinary but when I try to push the image_url into my array object, it returns an empty array.
What can i do?

Comment: console.log(urls) before "// Extracting" and console.log(pictureupload, idupload) before update profile.

Comment: @Bharath I did that already and I noticed that the Image_url is not being pushed to the ARR object I created.

Comment: You should learn to code with async, that's all

Comment: ForEach will not wait for cloudinary to finish its activity as suggested use async await or Promise.